# Assign dict values as arguments in Python

Tags: python, class, dictionary, arguments

I'm using a class

```
class Variable():
    def __init__(self, value, ratio):
    self.value = value
    self.ratio = {'A': 0.0, 'B': 0.0, 'C': 0.0}
```

and I would like to assign a value and a ratio (to one of `A`, `B` or `C`) when initializing, *i.e.*

```
> var1 = Variable(3.2, 'A'=100.0)
```

so that the outcome would be

```
> var1.value
3.2
> var1.ratio
{'A': 100.0, 'B': 0.0, 'C': 0.0}
```

Is this possible with a function argument like this, or should I use some other method?

Comment: There are many ways to do this - you can simply access and modify `ratio` after initializing `var1`, you can explicitly pass in parameters that are used to define `ratio`, you can pass in an entire `dict` to use. What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define default value for each parameter and use them directly into dict:

```
class Variable():
    def __init__(self, value, A=0.0, B=0.0, C=0.0):
        self.value = value
        self.ratio = {'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C}
```

and you are ready to go

```
var1 = Variable(3.2, A=100.0)
var1.ratio
{'A': 100.0, 'B': 0.0, 'C': 0.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
class Variable:
    def __init__(self, value, ratio):
        self.value = value
        self.ratio = {'A' : 0.0, 'B' : 0.0, 'C' : 0.0}
        self.ratio.update(ratio)

var1 = Variable(3.2, {'A' : 100.0})
print(var1.value) # 3.2
print(var1.ratio) # {'A': 100.0, 'B': 0.0, 'C': 0.0}
```